# Presenting a ViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

Does presenting a ViewController cause the presented controller to run its viewDidLoad method?

If a view1 is loaded and another is presented. Then something triggers to present view1. Will it run through its viewDidLoad method?

IF not how should this be done? ViewDidAppear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on what Jesse relayed, the `viewDidLoad` is called when the view is loaded into memory (usually the first time the view controller is ever about to be presented since app launch - simplified, but this will suffice for now).

When you display other view controllers and then come back some how to this original "view1" view controller, unless there was a memory event that jettisoned it from memory, it will NOT call `viewDidLoad` again.

Instead, it will call the following, in order:

1. `viewWillAppear:`
2. `viewDidAppear:`

In `viewWillAppear:`, you have a place to do things "off screen" before your view controller is displayed.

In `viewDidAppear:`, you can do additional operations that are appropriate for when the view controller's view is already visible. For example, you want to run some little animation that the user will see once the view controller is fully visible.

In both of these methods, make sure you call super's implementation before you do anything. Also, to learn about this lifecycle, set a breakpoint or NSLog() statement in each of these methods (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear) to see when they are called.

There's a concept piece in the Apple docs on View Controllers that is worth the 20 minute read - it'll clear up a lot of this key life cycle information about View Controllers, and these are *central* to iOS development. See the section "Understanding the View Management LifeCycle" at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW1

Comment: The thing is, I create a new instance of the viewController and present it. A new instance of View1

Comment: Often times, we reuse the same view controller instance and so my comments above hold in that sense. In your case, if you're instantiating a new object ("view1") at various points in your app, I would expect each new instantiation to trigger a hit to "viewDidLoad".

I'd put in some property variable like "name" that you can set each time you instantiate one of these. Do that. Then in viewDidLoad, spit out something like: 

NSLog(@"In viewDidLoad, for instance with name: %@", self.name); 

Studying this log output sequence will show you a definitive pattern you can plan with.

Answer (score 1):

viewDidLoad is only called when the view is loaded into memory. Usually the first time it appears (could be more often if there are memory dumps and etc).

viewDidAppear: is called every time the viewController's view becomes the 'active' view in the window.